# Cross-domain XMLHttpRequest request fails in headless chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cross-domain, headless

As the title says, I'm having problems making an headless chrome bot execute a XMLHttpRequest to another domain. The bot executes this code:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'http://localhost:30000/login', true);
xhr.withCredentials = true;
xhr.send(null);

xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    var DONE = 4; // readyState 4 means the request is done.
    var OK = 200; // status 200 is a successful return.
    if (xhr.readyState === DONE) {
        if (xhr.status === OK) {
            new Image().src='https://requestb.in/127kh4s1?c=OK';
        } else {
            new Image().src='https://requestb.in/127kh4s1?c=error-'+(xhr.status);
        }
    }
};
```

In my request bin the request are always ?c=error-0, indicating a fail with status code 0. When I visit the page manually, I get c=OK, which leads me to believe it's a problem with my bot.

From there I don't really know what to look for... The bot uses [chrome-remote-interface](https://github.com/cyrus-and/chrome-remote-interface) to interact with a chromium browser. The browser is started with these flags: "--headless", "--no-sandbox", "--disable-web-security".

Any suggestion what I should try next?

Comment: What is purpose of `xhr.withCredentials = true;`?

Comment: For now actually nothing, and I guess I should have removed it from my example. Nonetheless at some point I will be sending cookies set by the targeted websites along with my request, so I will need withCredentials to be set to true.

Comment: since you've set `--disable-web-security` then it is not `CORS`, could it be your `firewall`? closing the port : `3000`?